# converting a Mat object to double arr (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion

I wish to preforme an anistropic diffusion on a Mat object in opencv.
The anistropic is implemented in C and accepts the following:

```
applyFilter(double* I, Size sz, double theta, double scale, double eta)
```

I've searched in the documentation and online but havent found a sufficiant answer, how to convert my `Mat` object to `double[][]`, so i can run it through the function.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to check your Mat for 2 conditions:

- m.type() == CV_64FC1;     // 1channel double
- m.isContinuous() == true; // not padded or a roi

then you can safely use :

```
double *I = m.ptr<double>(0); // ptr to 1st row/element
```

Comment: Hey I've tried the following and it does accept the function, though when i try to convert the double back to mat im getting a blank white page, any ideas? I've tried both Mat(rows,cols,CV_64FC1, I) and copying the data manually using a for loop.

Comment: you might have to scale the values back to [0..1] range. try: `imshow("lala", I * 1.0/255);` // or some other factor. maybe even normalize() it.